# Wheeler-Regge analysis of $R \neq 0$ metric

Tags: general-relativity, metric-tensor, curvature, perturbation-theory, wormholes

I am trying to do a Wheeler-Regge analysis of a Morris-Thorne wormhole, but unfortunately, the Morris-Thorne wormhole is not Ricci-flat i.e. $R \neq 0$ where $R$ is the Ricci scalar, therefore, I am having trouble deriving the Wheeler-Regge equation for axial perturbations unlike the case of Schwartzschild metric where $R = 0$ and the Wheeler-Regge equation is straightforward to derive. Can anyone provide any suggestions as to how to go about deriving Wheeler-Regge equation for axial perturbations of $R \neq 0$ metrics?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Karlovini 2001, "axial pertubations of general spherically symmetric spacetimes", there is a description how to derive a two-dimensional wave equation as a twist potential for the axisymmetry generating Killing vector. As far as I can see it is not dependent on R=0: For example, they apply it for some kind of Maxwell fields and fluids, which aren't ricci-flat.
So you could probably try to follow their derivation for your special axialsymmetric problem of the wormhole.

Comment: Most grateful I am.